# Is there a XMLout type command for XML::Smart?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that I was opening with `XML::Simple`.  Now I want to do it with `XML::Smart`.

Is there a way in which I can print this in `XML::Smart`?

```
print XMLout( \%clean_xml, NoAttr => 1, RootName => $root_key, XMLDecl => 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `XML::Smart` POD: [CREATING-XML-DATA](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Smart#CREATING-XML-DATA)

```
## Create a null XML object:
my $XML = XML::Smart->new() ;
 
## Add a server to the list:
$XML->{server} = {
os => 'Linux' ,
type => 'mandrake' ,
version => 8.9 ,
address => '192.168.3.201' ,
} ;
 
## The data now:
## <server address="192.168.3.201" os="Linux" type="mandrake" version="8.9"/>

## Or save it directly:
$XML->save('newfile.xml') ;
```